# hover not working on all img elements

Tags: html, css, image, hover, opacity

I'm trying to add opacity to my images on hover, but it does not seem to work. I can englarge the image on hover and change the opacity on hover of other images, but the combo of opacity and hover will not work on the images below.
Any ideas?

```css
.portrait {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.portrait:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!--People-->
<section class='people' id='people'>
  <div class='photoContainer'>
    <h3>People</h3>
    <div class='flex'>
      <div class='portraitBlock' data-aos="zoom-in"></div>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/wes.png' alt='Wes Taylor' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="250"></img>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/john.png' alt='John Taylor' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="500"></img>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/larry.png' alt='Larry Kogut' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="750"></img>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/kathy.png' alt='Kathy Stewart' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="250"></img>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/sam.png' alt='Som Souvong' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="500"></img>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/assoc1.png' alt='Ashley Jenkins' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="750"></img>
      <img class='portrait' src='img/assoc2.png' alt='Savannah Frick' data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="1000"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's difficult to see the issue without valid links to the images. Other than that, it seems to work as expected. Incidentally, `<img>` tags "[m]ust have a start tag and *must not have an end tag*." -- [img @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Comment: It's working. Tested on Firefox and Chrome

Comment: This works for me on all elements. However, closing tags for the `img` element are not valid **HTML**.